# select max(pid) from ptable and display into textbox

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I have database which contains a column named `pid`. I want to select the `max(pid)` value and display it in a textbox. I tried the following:

```
 string query="select max(pid) from table";
 textbox.text=query;
```

But this code is not working for me. It just prints "select max(pid) from table" in the text box, not the result of that query. How can I correct this?

Comment: What data access would you like to uses? ADO.NET, nHibernate, a Linq Provider, Entity Framework?

Comment: @kmatyaszek:  MySql database

Comment: when i am using code  that i am geting "select max(pid) from table" into textbox not value of that

Comment: Have a look around for information on "how to call MySql from C#". There are lots of articles and samples you can find online. [This article](http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlcsharptutorial/) is pretty good.

Answer (score 4):

Here is some sample code showing how this can be done.  In short, you need to create an MySqlConnection to connect to you DB server, open it and then execute the posted SQL query.  Then, you can set the editor's Text property to the resulting value.

```
string conString = "SERVER=localhost;" +"DATABASE=mydatabase;" 
        "UID=aUser;" +"PASSWORD=aPassword;";
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(conString);
    conn.Open();
    try {
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("select max(pid) from table", conn);
        textBox1.Text = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    }
    finally {
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: still i have problem i am using .net connector to connect mysql

Comment: you must be sure that the conString you are passing is correct.  Set the breakpoint in this method and go from one line of code to another and check where it fails.

Comment: private void PatientRegistration_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("select max(pid) from table",con); this is my code i did not find any mistake still i don't understand
            txtpatientid.Text = command.ToString();
            con.Close(); 
             
        }

Comment: @user1961274 - You can [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14246772/edit) if you need to add additional information. (Then you can format it so it is easier for everyone to read).

Comment: you should call command.ExecuteScalar().toString();, not the command.ToString();

Comment: You should test for `DBNull` return value, in case there are no rows or all pid(s) are `NULL` : `object result = command.ExecuteScalar(); if (result != DBNull.Value) textBox1.Text = result.ToString(); else textBox1.Text = "no max";`

Answer (score 1):

All that code is going to do is display your query text in the textbox.  You need to connect to the database to run your query and get the results, then display the results in the textbox.

The native database framework for .NET is [**ADO.NET**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa286484.aspx).  You should start there.

Comment: MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("select max(pid) from table",con);
textbox.Text = command.ToString();
con.Close(); this is also not working for me

Comment: i can not get your answer

Comment: What is this?  Is this part of your code?

Comment: yes this is my code that is not working i only want to select max(pid) and want to display that into textbox like this textbox.text=cammand.tostring(); but it is not working

Comment: Please post your entire code in your original question.  This is much different than what your original question says.

Comment: i have a text box of dateofbirth and an other text box of current date how can i calculate age i have a text box of dateofbirth and an other text box of current date how can i calculate age i have a text box of dateofbirth and an other text box of current date how can i calculate age i have a text box of dateofbirth and an other text box of current date how can i calculate age `datetime()`

Comment: //there is problem in my code i can not understand is there any one help me who can i covert int value in tetbox in if statement int pid = Convert.ToInt32(txtid.Text.ToString());
            string query = "select pid from patientreg where pid=" + pid;
            int ptxtinput = 0;

            if (txtid.Text=query)
            {
                PatientRegistration preg = new PatientRegistration();
                preg.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                labelwrongid.Visible = true;
                labelwrongid.Text = "Your Id is not Available ";
            }